# Can't disconnect from a bonded BLE device (programming the BLE HID device)

Tags: bluetooth, arm, bluetooth-lowenergy, hid

I'm running a BLE HID device on a Sparkfun Artemis Thing Plug board. I can pair with the board and it works as a keyboard. What doesn't work is that, after pairing, I can't connect/disconnect. For example, if I look at my smart watch on my iPhone, the options for it look like follows:

[Disconnect option in the iPhone menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwTfp.png)

But for my HID device that's all there is:

[Lacking the disconnect option in the iPhone menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWb6y.png)

As you can see there is no *Disconnect* option. That's what I want to have for my HID device. I know that in order for the devices to pair only once they actually have to bond (pairing + saving the security information for any future connections). They bond correctly for sure. Resetting the HID BLE device results in iPhone and the device reconnecting. I just can't disconnect from the device with keeping the bonding information. I can only *Forget* the device.

Is it that the BLE device doesn't advertise properly and iPhone assumes that it's not a device that can be connected and disconnected from?

Answer (score 0):

For some strange reasons Apple has decided that it should not be possible to disconnect HID devices, only unpair them.